# Rails - how to debug CSS?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

My app works fine in development mode, I fail to push in to production however.

This is what I get from `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
(sass):1315
/Users/mohnstrudel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1189:in `expected'
/Users/mohnstrudel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1125:in `expected'
/Users/mohnstrudel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:42:in `parse'
/Users/mohnstrudel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:406:in `_to_tree'
... 
buch of lines
```

By using trial and error I narrowed the suspect down to bootstrap.min.css (it came bundled from template creator, using a plain bootstrap.min.css breaks the design).

Line 1315 and the code around looks like this:

```
.text-primary {
    color: #337ab7
}
a.text-primary:focus,
a.text-primary:hover {
    color: #286090 <-- this is exactly line 1315
}
.text-success {
    color: #3c763d
}
a.text-success:focus,
a.text-success:hover {
    color: #2b542c
}
```

This error is driving me mad, I can't even figure out what is wrong.
Is there a way to retrieve more informative error message?

Comment: Are you sure that's the file? The real bootstrap.min.css doesn't have as many lines as 1315.

Comment: @MrLister op said they they have a custom file from the theme creator

Comment: i wonder if the issue is the the comma + newline (versus putting it on one line), but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: @MrLister sorry, I did not mentioned it - it is a regular bootstrap css file, just titled as min.css. It has around 7700 lines.

maxpleaner I tried it already :( without any result.
I was wondering if there is a way, to show at least the full line where the error occured, not just the "}"

Comment: It's painful, but one option is to delete or comment out large chunks of the CSS until you can narrow it down to a specific line (sometimes the line number reported isn't the line that actually caused the problem, e.g., it could be a runaway string started on an earlier line).

Comment: @gmcnaughton Thanks! Your suggestion actually helped. I was able to break the css in chunks of halves and so on, narrowing my problem down to code line 68(!!) where there was this piece of code: `strong {
    font-family: ralewaybold;
}
}
dfn {
    font-style: italic
}`
Obviously, the double brackets cause all the trouble.